# What's the difference between *.b2 and *.rc1 software releases?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I've got 2 wxPython Phoenix wheels

```
wxPython-4.0.0b2-...
wxPython-4.0.0rc1.dev...
```

How do I know which one is the latest?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases